# Android SQLite Custom ListAdapter for AlertDialog SingleChoiceItems

Tags: android, sqlite, android-alertdialog, listadapter

I would like to create a Dialog where the user can select one radio option and click ok. The list items will have to hold both an id and text (but only text shows to the user) coming from sqlite db. Since setSingleChoiceItems accept a ListAdapter, I would probably need to create a custom List adapter and load items from my db select results. I actually need help to create this custom ListAdapter. Only after the user has clicked "ok", I would need to get the selected item text and id to save into respective SharePreferences fields.

Comment: Have you tried anything for this?

Comment: I have tried to declare a ListAdapter which it is accapted as an argument on my setSingleChoiceItems, to complete the adapter though I need help to update these methods: public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent), public long getItemId(int position) and other methods that makes a ListAdpter object.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I managed to set up my custom List Adapter but unfortunately the items are not showing as radios, this is my code:

```
    public void changePocket(View view)
{   
    ListAdapter liAdabter = new ListAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {

            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            PocketsObj pocketListItems = pocketsList.get(position);

            if (convertView == null) {

                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceID, parent, false); 
            }

            TextView idText = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.pocket_id);
            if (idText != null) {
                idText.setText(String.valueOf(pocketListItems._pocket_id));
            }
            TextView nameText = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.pocket_name);
            if (nameText != null) {
                nameText.setText(pocketListItems._pocket_name);
            } 
            return row;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {

            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {

            return pocketsList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return pocketsList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    };

     AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, 2);            
     alertBuilder.setTitle(R.string.change_pockets)
                .setSingleChoiceItems(liAdabter, 1,
                  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                   })
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.change_pockets_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.change_pockets_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        return;                         
                    }
                });

    alertBuilder.show();
}

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pocket_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pocket_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" >
    </TextView>
```